# What video container formats are similar to MPEG-TS?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, file-formats, live, formats

I have been looking to **live video streaming** where a client can join the stream of bytes and play the video automatically. I have recently found MPEG-TS which seems to work pretty well, and I noticed if I replace the .ts file with another format .mp4 or .mkv it doesn't work. I was just wondering if there are any alternative to MPEG-TS that I could test out, or is this the leading pioneer of this type of streaming?

Thanks

EDIT: Could I use a stream of h.264 bytes?

Comment: MPEG-TS is it..

Comment: Really wow, would have thought there would be other. Thanks for that.